# How to listen to changes made on javafx choicebox

Tags: java, javafx

I have a custom ChoiceBox which I am filling dynamically like so:

```
public class CustomChoiceBox {
    public void addItems(List<Item> items) {
        // Populate choicebox
        for(Item item : items) {
            CustomOption choice = new CustomOption(String.valueOf(item.getId()), item);
            this.getItems().add(choice);
        }
   }
}
```

CustomOption is a custom class defined as below:

```
public class CustomOption extends Observable{
    private String key;
    private Object value;

    public CustomOption(String key, Object value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
   }
}
```

I want to be able to listen to when the user makes a different choice and to get the value of that choice.
So I have added a listener :

```
myChoiceBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<CustomOption>() {
@Override
public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends CustomOption> observable,
    CustomOption oldValue, CustomOption newValue) {

        System.out.println(newVaue.getValue()); 
    }
});
```

However this code is not running when I change the choices. 
I have also tried using myChoiceBox.valueProperty()

Comment: Is it `CustomOption`, or `ChoiceBoxOption`? And presumably it is supposed to be `public class CustomChoiceBox extends ChoiceBox<CustomOption>` (or `ChoiceBox<ChoiceBoxOption>`, whichever you are actually using). If those are fixed, there is nothing obviously wrong with the code you have posted, so the problem likely lies elsewhere. You should create a [MCVE] and edit your question to include it.

Answer (score -1):

You could try by using the indexProperty instead of selected

```
final ChoiceBox<String> names = new ChoiceBox<String>();

names.getItems().add("john");
names.getItems().add("alex");
names.getItems().add("smith");

names.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
  @Override
  public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number number, Number number2) {
    System.out.println(names.getItems().get((Integer) number2));
  }
});
```